# Finding the inverse laplace of this function: $ F(s)= \frac{s+8}{s^{2}+4s+5}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, partial-fractions, completing-the-square

Im trying to find the inverse laplace of : $ F(s)= \frac{s+8}{s^{2}+4s+5}$

I reached the following: $$ F(s)= \frac{s}{(s+2)^{2}+1} + 8 \times \frac{1}{(s+2)^{2}+1}$$

Now i have the 2nd term in the right form, but my first one is not so im confused on how to go about putting it :S.

So basically in the first part how do i convert $ \frac{s}{(s+2)^{2}+1} to \frac{s+2}{(s+2)^{2}+1}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\cos\omega t) = \frac{s + a}{(s+a)^2 + \omega^2},$$ 
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\sin\omega t) = \frac{\omega}{(s+a)^2 + \omega^2}.$$
Then 
apply it to
$$
F(s)=\frac{s+\color{red}{2}}{(s+\color{red}{2})^{2}+1^2}+6\:\times\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{(s+2)^{2}+\color{blue}{1}^2} .
$$

Comment: in the first part how do i conver $\frac{s}{(s+2)^{2}+1} to \frac{s+2}{(s+2)^{2}+1} $?

Comment: ooooh i seeee that was pretty dumb of me :D!!! i got it

Comment: Using the last line in my answer, you get that the inverse Laplace transform you are looking for is $$e^{-2t}\left(\cos t+6 \sin t\right)$$ Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Divide it as $s+2$ and $6$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is not at all clear. Could you explain more?

Comment: Divide it as above and then use the formula: $$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\cos\omega t) = \frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2 + \omega^2}.$$